# Spring boot 2.6.6 MSSQL connection issue

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

After upgrading to spring boot 2.6.6 in production, constantly experiencing db connection issues
like

- com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The query has timed out. The query has timed out.
- connection is broken

current version for jdbc is 5.3.18 and r2dbc is 1.1.7

Does anybody experiencing the same issue ?

Comment: Query timeout is probably because the query is taking too long. I suggest you look at the query and query plan, as well as the relevant indexes, to get better diagnostics. Without this information we cannot help.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We did look at our query (we do need indexing haha).Everything was working fine until we patched our spring boot version. This error only occur during heavy traffic. Totally fine in our testing environment.

Comment: That doesn't mean much. There are many reasons why the server may choose a different query plan, and poor indexing means that it may have a difficult choice between many poor and very poor plans, rather than just one very obviously good one.

Comment: Okay Noted. Thank you for your suggestion. Will relook into our query plan and test it out.